# Problem building R package on Windows

Tags: r

I am experimenting with creating a sample R package. I generated the skeleton with:

```
package.skeleton(name = "hello",environment = .GlobalEnv, path = "c:", force = FALSE)
```

and build it with:

```
C:\>R CMD build hello
```

However, R output the following complains

```
* checking for file 'hello/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'hello':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... ERROR
During startup - Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return
= TRUE,  :
' there is no package called 'NULL
 in options("defaultPackages") was not found
```

I did some digging on Google. Some people seem to suggest that it is a certain character encoding issue. Though, I couldn't find any workaround. I am wondering if anyone here would know the solution?

*Updates*
I am using R 2.11.1 in the package provided by Revolution. The problem resolved after switching to R 2.12.1 from CRAN.

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of Windows? Which version of R?

Comment: Also, try it from the other end by downloading a (small, well-tested) CRAN package you know and running either one or both of `R CMD INSTALL` and `R CMD build --binary`.  That way you know toolkit, env. vars, ... are fine.

Comment: Which editor do you use to save your files? Do you have any "foreign" characters (like ščćžđ) in there? What is the encoding set to?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 and my editor is Vim with unix line break (\n). All characters in the packet are all regular english character. The R I use is 2.11.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates, I was using R 2.11.1 in the package provided by Revolution when I encountered the problem. The problem resolved after switching to R 2.12.1 from CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

The spec for package.skeleton() is:

```
package.skeleton(name = "anRpackage", list, environment = .GlobalEnv,
    path = ".", force = FALSE, namespace = FALSE,
    code_files = character())
```

That means "list" is not optional and you have to specify it. It is a list of objects to place in your project.

See here for how to do that:

> http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/utils/html/package.skeleton.html

Comment: From the url, "if list is omitted and code_files is empty, the contents of this environment are packaged." So, I think "list" is optional if the environment is supply. Beside, R didn't complain when I run the command

Comment: try using an empty vector as list, then tell if it worked or if we have to try something else.